# Magic mouse, tracking issue

Tags: mouse

So i love the magic mouse and was using a book/magazine as a mouse pad and was working fine. i then got a leather mouse pad and it too was working fine. However i replaced the batteries and now it is shocking on the leather pad. Very slow jumpy and intermittant tracking.

I understand that a leather pad probly isnt the best but was just wondering if anyone else has experienced the same or similar problem? fixes?

Comment: Maybe the batteries wasn't installed properly?

Comment: @revolver That's very unlikely, if they're installed incorrectly the mouse wouldn't turn on. Maybe there's some dust stuck in the hole next to the on/off switch?

Comment: DOES IT WORK ON PLAIN PAPER ?

Comment: One other thing to consider: it might not be an issue with the mouse reading the tracking, it might be an issue with the Bluetooth connection. You can see the signal strength if you open System Preferences > Bluetooth and then press opt (alt).  (Assuming 10.8 here.)